# Python time.sleep taking much longer

Tags: python, multithreading, boost-python

I am running an HTTP server (homemade, in C++) that embeds a Python interpreter for server-side scripting. This is a forking server, but I don't use any threading in any parent process. I don't do any weird things with the Python interpreter (other than the forks).

In one of the scripts, however, in another thread, a call to `time.sleep(0.1)` can take up to one minute, especially the first call.

```
while not self.should_stop():

    # other code

    print "[PYTHON]: Sleeping"
    time.sleep(0.1)
    print "[PYTHON]: Slept, checking should_stop"
```

I know that this is where it's hanging, because the logs show only the first print, and the second much, much later.

Additional information:

- the CPU is not pegged (~5%)
- this is Python 2.7 on Ubuntu
- These are `threading` threads; I do use locks and events where necessary.
- I don't import `threading` in any process that will ever do a fork
- Python is initialized before the forks; this works great elsewhere (no problems in the last 6 months)

Answer (score 0):

Python can run *[only one](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html)* `threading.Thread` at a time, so if there are many threads, the interpreter has to constantly switch between them, so one thread can run while the others get *freezed* or, in other words, interrupted.

But an interrupted thread isn't told that it's freezed, it's sort of falls unconscious for a while and then is woken up and *continues its work from where it has been interrupted*. So, 0.5 seconds for one particular thread may in fact turn out to be longer in real life.

Comment: Hi! Sorry, but can you provide a source, I've never heard anything like this before. Thanks!
Edit: Also, there are only 2 threads, why would one of them hang?

Comment: An hour of waiting for a half-second sleep would be a catastrophic thread scheduling deficiency, even with the global interpreter lock.

Comment: @user2357112, I thought it should be pretty obvious that it's an exaggeration, to show that the 'lag' may be quite noticeable.

Comment: A minute of waiting for a 0.1-second sleep, as reported in the question, would still be a catastrophic thread scheduling deficiency.

Comment: Maybe the runtime embedder (C++ code) has to explicitly allow other threads to run?

Comment: @EdwardB.: It's quite possible that you're doing something wrong on the C++ side, perhaps holding the GIL when you shouldn't or something like that. We'd need to see a [mcve] to diagnose the error; this would not be your entire C++ codebase, but it would be a heavily simplified, stripped-down example that still runs and demonstrates the problem when run.

Comment: That would be really hard to produce :(

Comment: Fixed! See my answer. It was indeed something that I wasn't doing embedding the runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed!

As it turns out, the main thread (the one embedding the interpreter, in C++) doesn't actually release the GIL when it's not executing Python code (as I imagined). You actually have to release the GIL manually, with `Py_BEGIN_ALLOW_THREADS` and `Py_END_ALLOW_THREADS`, as specified [here](https://docs.python.org/2.7/c-api/init.html#releasing-the-gil-from-extension-code).

This makes the runtime release the GIL so other threads can run during IO-intensive tasks (like, in my case, reading or writing to/from the network). No running Python code while doing that, though.